# Laravel- retrieve old values textbox in create form

Tags: css, json, database, laravel-5.5, tex

I need your help guys, I've created a form for creating Pay Bulletin and a form for editing. What i need is this:

Once i select emplyee_id the other textfield related popup with old data from DB if they are already entered; if not, i give them values and submit.

I am wondering how this can be done in Laravel??

[image]

Here is the code `create.blade.php`:

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('employeBultinDetails')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="paie_id">Mois du paie:</label>
          <select id="paie_id" name="paie_id" class="form-control">
              @foreach($paies as $p)
                <option value="{{$p->id}}">{{$p->mois}} - {{$p->annee}}</option> 
              @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>   

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="employe_id"> Employee:</label>

          <select id="employe_id" name="employe_id" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Selectionner l'employé...</option>
            @foreach($employes as $emp)
              <option value="{{$emp->id}}">{{$emp->nni}} : {{$emp->nomComplet}}</option> 
            @endforeach
          </select>

        </div>
      </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <table>
              <tr> 
                <th >Rubrique:</th> 
                <th >Montant:</th>
              </tr>

              @foreach($rubriques as $rub)
              <tr> 
                <td>{{$rub->libelle}}</td>

                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="montant[{{$rub->id}}]">
                </td>
              </tr>

              @endforeach
          </table>

        </div>
      </div> 

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:38px">Enregistrer</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
@endsection
```

Comment: Check my below code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('employeBultinDetails')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="paie_id">Mois du paie:</label>
          <select id="paie_id" name="paie_id" class="form-control">
              @foreach($paies as $p)
                <option value="{{$p->id}}">{{$p->mois}} - {{$p->annee}}</option> 
              @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>   

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="employe_id"> Employee:</label>

          <select id="employe_id" name="employe_id" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Selectionner l'employé...</option>
            @foreach($employes as $emp)
              <option value="{{$emp->id}}">{{$emp->nni}} : {{$emp->nomComplet}}</option> 
            @endforeach
          </select>

        </div>
      </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <table>
              <tr> 
                <th >Rubrique:</th> 
                <th >Montant:</th>
              </tr>

              @foreach($rubriques as $field => $rub)
              <tr> 
                <td>{{$rub->libelle}}</td>

                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="montant[{{$rub->id}}]" value="montant[{{old($field)}}]">
                </td>
              </tr>

              @endforeach
          </table>

        </div>
      </div> 

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:38px">Enregistrer</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
@endsection
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Patrik, but i think some thing needs to be setup in the create method. As i mentioned above thoses field are expected to display their values when i select the emplyee id.